# multiply all values in a column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas 1.14 and python 3.8

Given a dataframe:

```
Id      A      B
1       3      4
2       3      4
3       1      2
4       4      3
```

If I want to sum all values in A column I would simply to `sum(df["A"])`
How can I replace sum -> multiplication?

what I want is `multiply(df["A"])` which would return 3 x 3 x 1 x 4 = 36.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
df.A.product()
```

Comment: I think this is most straight forward. Thank you, I will mark it as an answer once I can(after 10mins).

Comment: btw you can use `df.A.prod()` as well, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html?highlight=series%20cumprod#pandas.Series.cumprod):

```
print(df['A'].cumprod())
```

Output:

```
0     3
1     9
2     9
3    36
dtype: int64
```

`cumprod` stands for "cumulative product", it multiplies the values with each other cumulatively.

Comment: Thank you I believe cumprod() definitely will be helpful in other problems as well!

Comment: @Ambleu Your welcome :-) `cumprod` stands for "cumulative product" Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Ambleu Added documentation link and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.prod(df["A"])
```

seems to do the trick! However if there is pandas way of doing it I would love to know!

Answer (score 0):

Lets try

```
 df.loc['prod','A']=df.A.prod(0)
```